# Methode ScriptApp.GetScriptTriggers" has been marked as outdated

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I am using this script [Send Google Form by Email v2.0](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/) (Amit Agarwal) but Google script gives the following message: 
"Methode ScriptApp.GetScriptTriggers" has been marked as outdated.
Is there an alternative methode?

Answer (score 4):

Please use getProjectTriggers() instead of getScriptTriggers().

```
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
```